# Lowercase letters in chapter titles in toc in classicthesis package

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` package and the `\chapter` creates uppercase lettered chapter titles in the toc. How can I change them to lowercase?

Comment: Welcome, they are smal capps lowercase. A design decision the template creator took. It really is supposed to look that way with the `classicthesis` style.

Answer (score 2):

With a **standard class** you can load KOMA-Script package `tocbasic` and redefine `\spacedlowsmallcaps` after ToC heading:

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[book.cls]{toc}
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{\listoftoc[{\contentsname}]{toc}}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\renewcommand\spacedlowsmallcaps[1]{#1}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[book.cls]{toc}
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{\listoftoc[{\contentsname}]{toc}}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\renewcommand\spacedlowsmallcaps[1]{#1}}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\end{document}
```

If you are using a **KOMA-Script class**, then you only have to redefine `\spacedlowsmallcaps` after ToC heading:

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\renewcommand\spacedlowsmallcaps[1]{#1}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just undo what classicthesis did:

`\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\normalfont}`.

This goes after the command that's loading classicthesis.sty.